# How to pass data to wordpress page (without GET parameter)

Tags: search

I've made a custom page for my wordpress website which will return custom results based on the data in the URL (not a search page).

Here's what it does:

The url is something like `http://example.com/CustomPage/BlaBla`, while landing on the page, it is supposed to read the last part (which is BlaBla) and return results based upon that.

But i'm getting a 404 error page every time. However i can use a query like `http://example.com/CustomPage?query=BlaBla` and do the trick, but i want the link to have a structure like the 1st one.

Is it possible to achieve this?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely possible to achieve this by using custom rewrite rules. Right now I don't have the opportunity to give you the actual code for it, but you can check the documentation for add_rewrite_rule() in the Codex. It's pretty straightforward if you add a custom parameter to the rewritten URL.

Actually, you already have the almost exact parameters for the function in your question.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [Rewrite tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag).

You can define custom tag and queries, and rewrite your custom URLs. After defining custom tag, follow [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) link and make a rewrite rule to create your new structure.

It's pretty easy if you follow the examples in these 2 links.